# Can't access my Gmail

Tags: gmail

I was trying to log into my gmail account when it said "looks like your signing in from an unusual location" then asked me to do step 2 verification. The strange thing about it is that the phone number and security question they asked are not any that I have set up and I am also using the same computer and internet I use every day. Please help me understand this, anyone!

Comment: It sounds like someone has been able to "steal" your account and use the security features against you. You should start with [Google Account Recovery](https://accounts.google.com/RecoverAccount?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F) and see if you can get your account back.

Comment: @AlEverett can you post that as an answer?

Comment: It's not much of an answer but okay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my Google account (or Gmail) password or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-account-or-gmail-password-or-username)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like someone has been able to "steal" your account and use the security features against you.

You should start with [Google Account Recovery](https://accounts.google.com/RecoverAccount?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F) and see if you can get your account back