# Can't get into my Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

Because of messages I received about the mail server being insecure, I was told to change my password. This I did with relative ease, got a "verification code" to use, went through two or three steps to verify this and thought all was well. However, when I try to log into my Gmail, it asks for my user name and password. Neither the new nor old credentials work.

What do I do now?

Comment: Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery and select _I don't know my password_, then follow the instructions given.

Comment: [How do I recover my Google password or username?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52706)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds *very* likely you got hit by a phishing attack that enabled someone else to take control over your account.  Unfortunately, short of contacting Google support, you likely have no meaningful recourse.