# How to disable "Verify it's you" on Gmail, without phone?

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

Sometimes, when I try to access my Gmail account from some other computer or country, an annoying security feature prevents me from doing so. I get the following message:

> Verify it's you
>
> There's something unusual about how you're signing in. To show that it's really you, complete the task below.

Below this, an option is offered:

> Enter a phone number to get a verification code by text message or phone call

But this doesn't help and doesn't even make any sense for me, because I didn't associate any phone number to my Gmail account and I don't intend to do so.

So, when I manage to log in, **how do I disable this "feature"?**

Is there any way to opt-out of additional verification and tell Google that I consider my password to be enough to log in my account (regardless of stuff like IP address and browser's user agent)?

Comment: Duplicate (unfortunately, no solution): [How to disable Gmail's login verification “There's something unusual about how you're signing in.”?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101058/354)

Comment: @ale I didn't notice it. Hopefully, somebody will come up with a solution, or at least with information whether there is a solution at all.

Comment: I was able to bypass the phone-only verification and get my account verified via my recovery email at https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery.

Comment: Solution is here: [How to disable Gmail's login verification “There's something unusual about how you're signing in.”?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101058/354)