# Recovering username for Google+ company page

Tags: google-plus

For a client I am updating website and company pages on Google+, Facebook, etc. However, the client lost his username for Google+; we tried recovering it using potential back-up email addresses but none of these worked. I do have access to the website the Google+ pages is linking to, and the home address that was used to verify the company.

Anyone has any clue how to recover this information and regain access to the Google+ page?

P.S.: I checked the [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-password-or-username) but the problem isn't covered there.