# Google redirects back to sign in page after entering correct username and password

Tags: google-account

I have the correct user name and password but when I enter them I just get put back to the sign in page in an endless loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my Google account (or Gmail) password or username?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-account-or-gmail-password-or-username)

Comment: I don't believe this is a lost password/username issue, so I'm voting to keep this question open. I have seen the problem myself. @Phil Wilde, try to clear your browser cache and cookies, and see if it helps.

Comment: Also, what web browser are you using, on what device?

Comment: After you do that, can you manually go to a different Google page, such as Gmail? Are you logged in then?

Comment: I voted to close this question as "Unclear what you are asking". Please add more details but bear in mind that the format of this site is not good for issues that require a lot of back and forth and that are related to issues that are specific for a single user.

Answer (score -1):

Try on another browser, if same problem try it on other device and check that you have right username and password.