# Opening a Gmail account

Tags: gmail

I have forgotten my Gmail account password and the phone number, Gmail is asking for sending a code,  is also deactivated. So how could I open my Gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening new account, you can recover your account with other ways. You can use secret question, alternate email or phone number.

Read this thread and try to recover: [How do I recover my Google account (or Gmail) password or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52706/87130)

To open new Gmail account follow this: [Create your Google Account](https://accounts.google.com/signup)