# Reopening a deleted Gmail account

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

How can I retrieve a deleted account? I used it a few years ago. I can remember the e-mail but not the password. When I tried to enter a certain password which I used (as far as I remember) it says:

> There are no Google Accounts that match your information.

How can I have it again?

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed [the steps to recover an account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52706/354) and Google is saying that no such account exists, you're out of luck. That account is permanently deleted.

According to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295), deleted accounts can be recovered if you attempt to recover them within **2-3 weeks** of their deletion. Beyond that they're gone forever.

Since Google does not recycle usernames, no one will ever be able to use that account again.

When (if) you make a new account, be sure to log into it every few months so this doesn't happen again.