# My Gmail account was taken over by someone in the country of Jordan

Tags: gmail, security, hacked

My wife's Gmail login [screen looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YAiI.jpg). I have changed her password, but it seems to go deeper into Gmail than that. There are ads served by Google in Arabic. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to set up Mozilla Thunderbird as a Gmail client? If so, check the language settings in Thunderbird.
If you believe the account has been taken over by someone, try [these suggestions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-account-or-gmail-password-or-username).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But those answers relate to recovering a lost password or username. I still can log in, but here are the problems.
This happens in the web version of gmail as well as in Thunderbird. When I start up Thunderbird it loads my personal and work accounts, but then asks for my wife's password. If I close that dialog box without entering the password, gmail loads her account into Thunderbird. When I start her account in the web version of gmail, I get the Arabic dialog box. Nothing else in the account is in the Arabic language.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of web version of Gmail. Also try login with some other browsers as well and share with us to help you in better way.

Comment: In my original message, click on the link - screen looks like this - and you'll see what I see when I go to mail.google.com. But as I said, I can close this dialog box without inserting the password and I am in the gmail account. Is this just a way to get the password and send it back to the hacker? It's annoying to have to close it every time.