# How to prove that I'm the owner of a hacked google account

Tags: gmail, google-account, hacked

**Please read the question before marking it as duplicate! It says that I know that standard answers and that I understand the WHYs, but that I have a different case. "You case is ignored by Google" would be a valid answer, "This is duplicate" is not true. Thank you.**

Someone hacked my (free) google account, and I tried all the well-known steps to regain access to it (don't link them, I know them). Obviously, I can't answer those questions good enough to convince the system that it's my account. Well, it's fair to make it difficult to reset a password for security reasons.

But I can prove I'm the owner: The domain of the e-mail address I used to create the account (which is still the valid contact address) belonged to me since ever. So you could think of enough ways to prove that I'm the real owner of the account.

Unfortunally, none of those scenarios is part of the default account verification and it seems impossible to contact a real human about this issue.

If there is no way to regain access, it would be okay for me to delete the said account and create a new one. Do I have a chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my Google account (or Gmail) password or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-account-or-gmail-password-or-username)

Comment: That's one of the Q&A I did read and that doesn't cover my case, so no duplicate.

Comment: "I have forgotten the password for my private Google (Gmail) account" part of accepted answer seems like your case

Comment: No, this answer leads to a point, when Google says that you can only prove to have *access* to that e-mail (which is not sufficient, of course), but I can also prove that it's mine (which almost all users can't). Didn't I write that?

Comment: Everything we know about Google Account recovery is in the answer to that duplicate.

Comment: Actually not, as the given answer shows. (-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet to get effective help when you already tried "all" to recover a Google Account is https://support.google.com/accounts/community

There a [Product Expert](https://support.google.com/communities/answer/9138806?hl=en) (not an employee) a Product Specialist or a Community Manager could reply to your post providing additional guidance if it applies.

**Disclaimer**: I'm a Google Account Product Expert but usually I only participate on threads wrote in Spanish.