# Is it possible to access a Google account using a recovery address without changing the password?

Tags: google-account, security, account-recovery, passwords

I realized that the password of one of my Google accounts has probably been compromised for more than a year or so. I already changed the password of that account, however I am worried about other Google accounts that were linked to this account (like recovery address). Is there a way I can be sure that those other accounts were not accessed using my compromised account?

If I am able to log-in to my other accounts using their passwords (they have different passwords than the compromised one), then is it a sure guarantee that those accounts were not accessed by using the compromised recovery address? In other words, is it possible (or has it been in the last couple of years at least) to access a Google account using their recovery address without changing/resetting the password?

Comment: Welcome. Please narrow the question to a single service. You might post another question to ask about the other service.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks. Narrowed it to Google only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google account access can only be done having signed in using a valid password and under certain circumstances it could require that the user also use another method to validate the they should have access to the account.

The only way to get a link to access a Google account is by following the required steps to recover it which always will require to set a new password.

Related

- [How do I recover my Google account (or Gmail) password or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52706/88163)

Comment: "*...which always will require to set a new password*" - that's the key part. So I can rest assured that as long as I can log-in to my Google account using my old password, that account has **not** been accessed using a compromised recovery address. Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly. It's better to do the security check-up and to change your password frequently. The security check-up for the Google account is done from the account settings.