# Help me get back into my account

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

My old phone was lost or stolen so I'm trying to log into my Google account from a different phone but I dont remember my pass word and I didnt have a recovery email..I tried to use my girlfriends email but google said it couldn't verify it was me..so I dont know what to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my Google account (or Gmail) password or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-account-or-gmail-password-or-username)

Answer (score -1):

If you used your cellphone number  to create the Goggle account what you can do go do a sim swap after that go to Gmail put your Gmail account then press forgot password there will send you a code on your cellphone then you can reset your passwords.