# Replace old Authenticator option in my Google account

Tags: google-account, account-management, multi-factor-auth

This question is different from the suggested duplicate, [How do I recover my Google (or Gmail) account, password, or username?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-or-gmail-account-password-or-username)  That question was about recovering a Google account. My question is different because I went through that process and it worked however I still cannot access my 2FA menu.

---

Years ago while living abroad I created a secondary Google account and used the email address for online services, while forwarding incoming messages to my main account.

Recently Google sent an "[Inactive Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/12418290?hl=en)" warning directing me to login to the secondary account in order to keep it active.

I was able to login correctly.
However during the process, I realized I no longer have the phone where the Google Authenticator app was installed, nor did I make a copy of the backup authentication codes.   I do still have access to the old foreign phone number associated with the account, and can receive SMS if needed.

I want to update the phone number associated with my secondary account and the 2FA settings to use my current Google Authenticator app to ensure I'm not locked out of my account in the future and to shut down the foreign phone number which I am paying to maintain.

In my Google account, when I try to change any of the security settings, it asks me for an authenticator code, which I am unable to provide.

When I click "More ways to verify", it does not offer a verification option using the associated number or recovery address.  It shows only: "Get a verification code from the Google Authenticator app."

I have searched Google support but cannot find how to verify changes to my 2FA settings by SMS or recovery address.

Comment: Have you tried to [Turn off 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en) and then turn it back on?  See also [How to recover your Google Account or Gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/76824390) and [Tips to complete account recovery steps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7299973) and [BlogSpot: Account Recovery Walk-Through](https://gmailaccountrecovery.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Yes, I tried to access the 2gStep Verification menu, but at step 3 google asks me for the authentication codes, and does not offer to use back up solutions for authentication. I also went through the recovery process to see if it would improve things, but it is still the same.

Comment: It looks like you are left with  [Recovering the account](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/recoveryidentifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AccountRecovery)  Given that it's your account, and you still have access to the associated email and mobile number, I expect it to be relatively straightforward.  Your trusted device is gone, without a replacement. SMS verification is not used in these cases as Google can trigger a security pop-up on any of your trusted devices. That is why you are offered one option which would prove you had trusted access to the trusted device.

Comment: This Page is very comprehensive:[BlogSpot: Gmail Account Recovery](https://gmailaccountrecovery.blogspot.com/?m=0)

Comment: Remember that troubleshooting like questions, by community consensus, are off-topic on this site. I suggest you go to the [Google Accounts official community](https://support.google.com/accounts/community) and try the contact options offered by Google to you.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147627/discussion-on-question-by-wip-replace-old-authenticator-option-in-my-google-acco); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.